# sed/awk replace in all matches

Tags: regex, sed, awk

I want to invert all the color values in a bunch of files. The colors are all in the hex format `#ff3300` so the inversion could be done characterwise with the sed command

```
y/0123456789abcdef/fedcba9876543210/
```

How can I loop through all the color matches and do the char translation in sed or awk?

EDIT:

sample input:

```
random text... #ffffff_random_text_#000000__
asdf#00ff00
asdfghj
```

desired output:

```
random text... #000000_random_text_#ffffff__
asdf#ff00ff
asdfghj
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*EDIT*: I changed my response as per your edit.

OK, `sed` may result in a difficult processing. `awk` could do the trick more or less easily, but I find `perl` much more easy for this task:

```
$ perl -pe 's/#[0-9a-f]+/$&=~tr%0123456789abcdef%fedcba9876543210%r/ge' <infile >outfile
```

Basically you find the pattern, then execute the right-hand side, which executes the tr on the match, and substitutes the value there.

Comment: sorry, I wasn't clear what the files are like, I edited the question post

Comment: Remember this version is case sensitive for the hex numbers.

Comment: @Jite, yes, as it is in the original question.

Comment: @DiegoSevilla - Yes, it wasn't meant as something negative towards your solution, I just wanted to make sceid aware of it to prevent future problems :)

Comment: I get bareword and other errors because of the "r" after the last `%`. If I remove the "r" (which I don't find in the documentation), I get this error: "Modification of a read-only value attempted".

Comment: I also get the same errors and can't get it work, although I understand the idea and like this solution. @DiegoSevilla - have you tried running it?

Comment: @Jite - Thanks for the comment, I didnt forget about case sensitivity, I just tried to keep it simple, I can handle that afterwards.

Comment: @sceid, yes, it is working. Maybe my version of `perl` is newer. `r` stands for returning the substitution instead of performing it. Look here for example: http://perldoc.perl.org/perlop.html#Quote-Like-Operators

Comment: @DiegoSevilla - you're right, it died in v5.10.1 but worked in v5.14.2, thanks!

Answer (score 2):

The inversion is really a *subtraction*. To invert a hex, you just subtract it from `ffffff`.
With this in mind, you can build a simple script to process each line, extract hexes, invert them, and inject them back to the line.

---

This is using **Bash** (see arrays, `printf -v`, `+=` etc) only (no external tools there):

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

[[ -f $1 ]] || { printf "error: cannot find file: %s\n" "$1" >&2; exit 1; }

while read -r; do
    # split line with '#' as separator
    IFS='#' toks=( $REPLY )
    for tok in "${toks[@]}"; do
        # extract hex
        read -n6 hex <<< "$tok"
        # is it really a hex ?
        if [[ $hex =~ [0-9a-fA-F]{6} ]]; then
            # compute inversion
            inv="$((16#ffffff - 16#$hex))"
            # zero pad the result
            printf -v inv "%06x" "$inv"
            # replace hex with inv
            tok="${tok/$hex/$inv}"
        fi
        # build the modified line
        line+="#$tok"
    done
    # print the modified line and clean it for reuse
    printf "%s\n" "${line#\#}"
    unset line
done < "$1"
```

---

use it like:

```
$ ./invhex infile > outfile
```

test case input:

```
random text... #ffffff_random_text_#000000__
asdf#00ff00
bdf#cvb_foo
asdfghj
#bdfg
```

processed output:

```
random text... #000000_random_text_#ffffff__
asdf#ff00ff
bdf#cvb_foo
asdfghj
#bdfg
```

Answer (score 2):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed '/#[a-f0-9]\{6\}\>/!b
s//\n&/g
h
s/[^\n]*\(\n.\{7\}\)[^\n]*/\1/g
y/0123456789abcdef/fedcba9876543210/
H
g
:a;s/\n.\{7\}\(.*\n\)\n\(.\{7\}\)/\2\1/;ta
s/\n//' file
```

Explanation:

- `/#[a-f0-9]\{6\}\>/!b` bail out on lines not containing the required pattern
- `s//\n&/g` prepend every pattern with a newline
- `h` copy this to the hold space
- `s/[^\n]*\(\n.\{7\}\)[^\n]*/\1/g` delete everything but the required pattern(s)
- `y/0123456789abcdef/fedcba9876543210/` transform the pattern(s)
- `H` append the new pattern(s) to the hold space
- `g` overwrite the pattern space with the contents of the hold space
- `:a;s/\n.\{7\}\(.*\n\)\n\(.\{7\}\)/\2\1/;ta` replace the old pattern(s) with the new.
- `s/\n//` remove the newline artifact from the `H` command.

Answer (score 1):

This works...

```
cat test.txt |sed -e 's/\#\([0123456789abcdef]\{6\}\)/\n\#\1\n/g' |sed -e ' /^#.*/ y/0123456789abcdef/fedcba9876543210/' | awk '{lastType=type;type= substr($0,1,1)=="#";} type==lastType && length(line)>0 {print line;line=$0} type!=lastType {line=line$0} length(line)==0 {line=$0} END {print line}'
```

The first sed command inserts line breaks around the hex codes, then it is possible to make the substitution on all lines starting with a hash. There are probably an elegant solution to merge the lines back again, but the awk command does the job. The only assumption there is that there won't be two hex-codes following directly after each other. If so, this step has to be revised.

Comment: No need to pipe sed to sed since you already use the -e flag, just make it `sed -e 'expr' -e 'expr2'`.

Comment: I tried that, but for some reason it does not work... Any explanation?

Comment: You made some bad syntax most likely because it does work :) Just don't forget to add another -e before the next expression